# I'm using an Image component (with an external source) in React Native on iOS and the image is disappearing when the app is resumed?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

To reiterate, I'm using React Native with iOS.

I'm using an Image component that has the source set to an external GIF image (from Giphy). This is working perfectly fine. However, when you press the home button on the device and then go back into the app to resume it, the image component is blank. The other text elements retain their data just fine.

Is there a way to keep the image set when the app is resumed? Or an event that happens when the app is resumed, so I can manually set the source again?

Comment: I don't know anywhere near enough about iOS to answer, but it might be worth it to download the gif and load the downloaded gif, since you have to access it anyway.

Comment: You know what, that might be my best bet. I'm going to give that a try.

Comment: Lemme know if it works -- if it does, I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue too. It seems like a react native bug. I just using animation instead of gif to solve this issue.